# Magento Thub Quickbooks Integration

Tags: xml, magento, quickbooks

Hopefully someone on here has some Thub experience with magento and quickbooks. Here is my problem:

We created a bundled item in Magento with 2 t-shirts (configurable) and 4 other simple products that can't be changed. When you select this pack you have to select the size of shirt. Our config product might be 1002 with the simple product options 1002:S, 1002:M, 1002:L for Small Medium Large. Then they select the next shirt size 1003:S, 1003:M etc. They purchase the order at a set price. We have everything set up to where the order processes and everything. Our problem is with Thub and Quickbooks. When Magento sends the order it shows only the SKU number of the bundled item and because it's dynamic and changing we can't make a group item in quickbooks for all the possibilities.

I have found these answers on thub support but these solutions will not work.

http://www.support.atandra.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/49/0/using-group-items-in-quickbooks

http://www.support.atandra.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/74/0/downloading-orders-from-magento-containing-bundled-products

Does anyone know of a way we can separate each item after the order is being sent so that thub and quickbooks integrates easily?

Hopefully I explained it so you can get what we are trying to do. Thank you everyone for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can map items from Magento to Quickbooks so that your group product selection equals something else in quickbooks.

If I understand correctly:

You have an product as a base with sku 12345 and a config option that's 12345B. Maybe on the order it shows the sku at 12345-12345B or :, basically combines them in some way.

In t-hub you can use item mapping to match one sku from magento (input the 12345-12345B) to the corresponding sku in quickbooks (like 12345b). So it basically says all orders containing sku 12345-12345B equals the 12345b sku in quickbooks. You can export this list and do it via excel and import.

About item mapping from their docs:

http://www.atandra.com/library/docs/thub10/THUB_Manual.htm#_Toc337359363

Hope that helps!